# An expression for sin(40)

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, cubics

I am trying to find an expression for $\sin(40)$ in the following way:
Let

$\theta$ = 40

3$\theta$=120

$\sin(3\theta)$=sin(120)

$-4\sin^3(\theta)+3\sin(\theta)=\frac {\sqrt 3} 2 $

Put $\sin(\theta)=x$

$-4x^3+3x=\frac {\sqrt 3}2$

$x^3-\frac 34x=\frac {\sqrt 3}{-8}$

We have to solve this cubic equation. I will brought it in the the form $x^3+q=px$. Now I apply the Cardan Formula.The original formula shows roots for $x^3+px=q$. I am putting $-p$ for $p$ and $-q$ for $q$ to get the formula:

$x=\sqrt[3] {\frac {-q}2+ \sqrt{{\frac{q^2}4}-{\frac{p^3}{27}}}}+\sqrt[3] {\frac {-q}2- \sqrt{{\frac{q^2}4}-{\frac{p^3}{27}}}}$

The quantity under square root reduces to $\frac {-1}{256}$.Upon Simplyfying I found the that

$x=\sqrt[3] \frac {-\sqrt 3 +\sqrt{-1}} {16}+\sqrt[3] \frac {-\sqrt 3 -\sqrt{-1}} {16}$

$x=\frac 12{\sqrt[3] \frac {-\sqrt 3 +\sqrt{-1}} {2}+\sqrt[3] \frac {-\sqrt 3 -\sqrt{-1}} {2}}$

This is one complex root of the cubic. Now I simplified this cube roots:

$-\sqrt 3 +i=\text{(polar form)}\:2,150$

$\sqrt[3] {-\sqrt 3 +i}=2^{1/3},50=2^{1/3}(\cos(50)+i \sin(50))$

$\sqrt[3] {-\sqrt 3 -i}=2^{1/3},10=2^{1/3}(\cos(10)+i \sin(10))$

Am I right here? Otherwise How should I continue to find an expression for sin(40).

Please help.

Comment: hmm, the cubic equation should have three real roots (instead of complex), looking at the graph. So there must just be some small mistake you made at some point.

Comment: The determinant is
$$
D = -108\left( \frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} \right) = \frac{27}{64}>0
$$
So indeed the roots should all be real and distinct.

Comment: @MattiP.  The other 2 roots are $\sin (160^o)$ and $\sin (-80^o)$ because $160^o$ and $(-80^o)$ are the other 2 solutions (for $\theta$) of  $\sin  (3\theta)=\sin (120^o). $

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a cleaner answer using this identity:
$$\sin x=\frac{1}{2} i e^{-i x}-\frac{1}{2} i e^{i x}$$
Thus for $40^\circ=\frac{2\pi}9$, you get:
$$\begin{align}\sin 40^\circ&=\frac{1}{2} i e^{-\frac{1}{9} (2 i \pi )}-\frac{1}{2} i e^{\frac{2 i \pi }{9}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{5/18} \left((-1)^{4/9}-1\right)
\end{align}$$

---

From $f(x)=-4x^3+3x-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=0$, we get the roots using Cardano's for $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ formula using:
$$x_1=-\frac{b}{3 a}+S+T\\
x_2=-\frac{b}{3 a}+\frac{1}{2} \left(i \sqrt{3}\right) (S-T)-\frac{S+T}{2}\\
x_3=-\frac{b}{3 a}-\frac{1}{2} \left(i \sqrt{3}\right) (S-T)-\frac{S+T}{2}$$
Where:
$$S=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{Q^3+R^2}+R}\\
T=\sqrt[3]{R-\sqrt{Q^3+R^2}}$$
Where:
$$Q=\frac{3 a c-b^2}{9 a^2}\\
R=\frac{-27 a^2 d+9 a b c-2 b^3}{54 a^3}$$
For $f(x)$, we get:
$$Q=-\frac{1}{4}\\
R=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}$$
For $S$ and $T$, we get:
$$S=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}+\frac{i}{16}}\\
T=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}-\frac{i}{16}}$$
And thus we get roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$ as:
$$x_1=\frac{\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{3}-i}+\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{3}+i}}{2 \sqrt[3]{2}}\\
x_2=\frac{\left(-1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{3}-i}+i \sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{3}+i} \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)}{4 \sqrt[3]{2}}\\
x_3=\frac{i \left(\left(-\sqrt{3}+i\right)^{4/3}-\left(-\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{4/3}\right)}{4 \sqrt[3]{2}}$$
Evaluating these numerically, we get that $x_1$ is the only correct answer. Take not too that all these roots are real because $D<0$